# Find a set of value within a table that compares counts based two different criteria and matches the count [ms-access]

Tags: ms-access

I have a table:

**TEST1**

```
+-------+----------+-------------+--------+
| AppID | Platform |  Category   | Status |
+-------+----------+-------------+--------+
|  1234 | AA       | Application | ON     |
|  1234 | BB       | WAN         | OFF    |
|  1234 | CC       | Application | ON     |
|  2222 | DD       | Application | OFF    |
|  2222 | EE       | WAN         | OFF    |
|  2222 | FF       | Application | ON     |
+-------+----------+-------------+--------+
```

I would like to find all AppIDs with `Category = 'Application'` and **ALL** rows with `Status = 'ON'`. In the above example, AppID `1234` meets that criteria.

I tried to use the following query but it returns no result. (The right result should just be AppID: `1234`).

Any suggestions?

```
SELECT AppID
FROM TEST1
WHERE Category = "Application" 
GROUP BY AppID
HAVING 
Count(AppID) = (Select count(AppID) from TEST1 WHERE Category="Application" AND Status="ON")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
select t.appid
from test1 t
where t.category = 'Application'
group by t.appid
having min(t.status) = max(t.status) and min(t.status) = 'ON'
```

Or alternatively, using a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct t.appid
from test1 t
where t.category = 'Application' and not exists
(
    select 1 
    from test1 u 
    where u.appid = t.appid and u.category = 'Application' and u.status <> 'ON'
)
```

Or using a joined subquery:

```
select distinct t.appid
from test1 t left join 
(
    select u.appid 
    from test1 u 
    where u.category = 'Application' and u.status <> 'ON'
) v 
on t.appid = v.appid
where t.category = 'Application' and v.appid is null
```